# Utilizing Gemini: Through Vertex AI or through Google/generative-ai?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini, gemini

I'm in the process of developing a chatbot application and I'm exploring options for integrating Gemini, a large language model (LLM).

I'm considering whether to utilize Vertex AI (@google-cloud/vertexai) for integration or to directly incorporate Gemini (@google/generative-ai)

**google-cloud/vertexai:**

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/quickstart-multimodal

**google/generative-ai:**

https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/node_quickstart.

Given that Gemini is an LLM and Vertex AI is a platform, I'm seeking insights on which  approach might be more suitable for my project.  Any recommendations or considerations would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: If you are serious about learning Google Cloud AI, learn both. If you want to be a carpenter, would you only learn how to use a hammer?

Comment: Thank you.  I'm familiar with both methods,  but as a developer, I believe utilizing Gemini through Vertex AI is the best option for app integration. However, I'm still unsure. I'm seeking insights from someone who has used it or has an idea to ensure accuracy.

Comment: Google provides two APIs to access Google Gemini: [Google AI Gemini API](https://ai.google.dev/docs/gemini_api_overview) and `Google Cloud Vertex AI Gemini API`. The first API supports Gemini models and has a simple API interface and uses an API key. The second API is more complex and supports integration with other Cloud services, IAM, service accounts, etc. The first API is built to support mobile devices and Firebase as well. The second API is built for backend services. In summary, the first API is designed for simpler use cases and ease of integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gemini is a large language model as you specified. You can use it (via API calls) by calling either Google AI APIs or Vertex AI APIs.

If you are relatively new to Gemini and wants to explore the feature and build some prototype for your chatbot app, Google AI APIs (with Google AI Studio) is a fast way to get started. While your app and idea matures and you'd like to leverage more MLOps tools that streamline the usage, deployment, and monitoring of models, you can move to Google Cloud Vertex AI which provides Gemini APIs along with many other features. Basically, to help you productionize your app.

Depending on your app requirement and stages of your development, you can choose the path:

- Start with Google AI Studio and [migrate Gemini app to Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/migrate/migrate-google-ai#python-migrate)
- Prototype and build with Vertex AI if you already have GCP established.

Pay attention to the [Google AI vs. Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/migrate/migrate-google-ai#google-ai) differences when making decision.

Comment: Thank you for your input! After considering your advice, I've decided to directly incorporate Gemini through Vertex AI for our chatbot application. Your guidance was instrumental in making this decision. Much appreciated !

Comment: Is Gemini AI through Vertex AI (Google Cloud/Vertex AI) currently available on a pay-as-you-go basis, or are there limitations such as 60 queries per minute?   I'm considering integrating it into my Chatbot application.

Comment: Please see pricing page https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/pricing#:~:text=Media%20input%20is%20charged%20per,$0.000375%20/%201k